# New Water Pump Hard to Turn

Tags: toyota, corolla, water-pump

I was told that when a pulley of an engine component does not turn freely, it it probably starting to seize. By diagnoising all the pullies attached to my engine, I identified the water pump pulley as beginning to seize. Therefore, I bought a new water pump for my Toyota Corolla 2003. I was astonished to discover that upon trying to spin the pulley on my new water pump the pulley did not spin freely either.

Is the new water pump broken? Or is the fact that the pulley not installed justify that fact that the pulley of the new pump not spin freely?

If it might help I bought a Beck/Arnley water pump.

Thank you for your response!

Regards

Comment: Define "hard to turn" yes new pumps have more resistance to turning than used ones, this is normal.

Comment: The new water pump is hard to turn in the sense it does not spin freely when trying to turn it. I have to use my hand to make it do a whole 360 degree turn.

Comment: This is normal for a New pump.